# JQuery get calling <script> tag when dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, magicsuggest

> How can I locate the  tag which calls a JQuery script, when
>   the  tag is dynamically loaded, so won't be the last 
>   tag on the page?

I'm using the [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/) autosuggest library. I want to give certain suggested items a different background color depending on their contents, which I'm currently doing by adding JQuery inside a  tag, which I'm adding on to the String which is returned to be rendered inside the selection div. Then, to get the div the item is suggested in, I need to essentially get the parent() of the  tag, and change it's css() properties. How can I get this current script tag however?

I'm currently assigned each new  tag an id generated from incrementing a JS variable - which works, but isn't very 'nice'! Is there anyway I can directly target the tag with JQuery?

If it perhaps makes it clearer, here is my current selectionRenderer function.

```
selectionRenderer: function(a){
                    var toRet =  a.english;
                    var blueBgScript = "<script id=ft" + freeTextFieldID + ">$('#ft" + freeTextFieldID + "').parent().css('background', 'blue');</script>"
                    if(a.id==a.english){
                        toRet += blueBgScript;
                        freeTextFieldID++;
                    }
                    return toRet;
                },
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your application code? Perhaps you could create a [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/) and link it?

Looking at the [MagicSuggest examples](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/) you should be able to get the suggested elements with something like $("#ms-res-ctn-0").children()

Comment: Create a unique string that only appears there (server's time + token is a good candidate). Then, you can can select the script tags and use a string search on their contents.

Comment: why don't you just... add the style to the element when you generate the element html?

Comment: The HTML is generated by the MagicSuggest library - from where I am now, I only have control over the innerHTML of the generated div tag...unless I start messing around with the library.

Comment: smholloway - I'll try and knock up a jsfiddle later. The ID you put is dependent on how many items have already been selected in the list...which I don't THINK I'll be able to know...
Benjamin - that's basically what I'm doing at the moment isn't it, generating a unique, random bit of information for the script tag, and hunting it down. I was just wondering if there was a nicer way of selecting through DOM. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add some code at `afterrender` event instead? Add some tag to flag the options that need a different background, then detect the parents and add a class (or edit the bg property) or whatever you like:

```
var newMS = $('#idStr').magicSuggest({
                data: 'states.php',
                displayField: 'english',
                valueField: 'id',           
                selectionRenderer: function(a){
                    var toRet =  a.english;
                    if(a.id==a.english) toRet = "<span class='freetext'>" + toRet + "</span>";
                    return toRet;
                },
            });

$(newMS).on('selectionchange', function(event,combo,selection){
    var selDivs = $(event.target._valueContainer[0].parentNode).children('div');            //Get all the divs in the selction 
    $.each(selDivs,function(index,value){                               //For each selected item
        var span = $(value).children('.freetext');                      //It if contains a span of class freetext
        if(span.length == 1) $(value).css('background','blue');         //Turn the background blue
    });
```

Comment: This is the beauty of StackOverflow...different ways of looking at the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: Replaced the example with some working code - thanks for the idea!